# Sending grouped json data with ajax

Tags: json, extjs

I'm using extJS version 4.0 to generate a entry form. On that form there is a save button that sends all the fielddata to php via ajax. As transfer protocol for the data itself I'm using json.

As I need to make a dynamical (general) routine for processing this data (as that one form won't be the only form in that project) I would need that json data grouped somehow. One of the requirements I have is that I need the "fieldnames" to be as they are (as I use the fieldnames I get transmitted to me to access the approopriate coloumns in the database in the automatic save routine).

My question here is is there any way to somehow group the data that is transmitted via json (thus that extJS groups it). 
As a simplified example:

On the entryform I'm saving data for 2 tables (1. Person 2. bankaccount) which have the following fields shown on the form:
-firstname
-lastname
for person
and 
-account number
-bank number
for bankaccount
(the stores are accordingly)

Is there a way with extJS to group this data acordingly, thus generate something like this?

```
{"person":[{"firstname": "Mark", "lastname":"Smith"}],"bankaccount":[{"account number":123112,"bank number":1A22A1}]}
```

Currently I'm getting something like this:

```
{"firstname": "Mark", "lastname":"Smith","account number":123112,"bank number":1A22A1}
```

Both person and bankaccount  are in their separate stores.

Tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you've two stores: one for 'person' and one for 'bankaccount'.

```
Ext.define ('Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model' ,
    fields: ['firstname', 'lastname']
});

Ext.define ('BankAccount', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model' ,
    fields: ['accountnumber', 'banknumber']
});

var personStore = Ext.create ('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Person' ,
    data: [
        {firstname: 'foo', lastname: 'bar'} ,
        {firstname: 'zoo', lastname: 'zar'} ,
        {firstname: 'too', lastname: 'tar'} ,
        {firstname: 'goo', lastname: 'gar'} ,
        {firstname: 'moo', lastname: 'mar'}
    ]
});

var bankAccountStore = Ext.create ('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'BankAccount' ,
    data: [
        {accountnumber: 10000, banknumber: 10000} ,
        {accountnumber: 20000, banknumber: 20000} ,
        {accountnumber: 30000, banknumber: 30000} ,
        {accountnumber: 40000, banknumber: 40000} ,
        {accountnumber: 50000, banknumber: 50000}
    ]
});
```

Then, you want to dump these stores as JSON. No problem!
Make a container (*jsonData*) and then fill it up with your stores:

```
var jsonData = {
    person: [] ,
    bankaccount: []
};

personStore.each (function (person) {
    jsonData.person.push (person.data);
});

bankAccountStore.each (function (bank) {
    jsonData.bankaccount.push (bank.data);
});

console.log (Ext.JSON.encode (jsonData));
```

And this is the output on the console:

```
{"person":[{"firstname":"foo","lastname":"bar"},{"firstname":"zoo","lastname":"zar"},{"firstname":"too","lastname":"tar"},{"firstname":"goo","lastname":"gar"},{"firstname":"moo","lastname":"mar"}],"bankaccount":[{"accountnumber":10000,"banknumber":10000},{"accountnumber":20000,"banknumber":20000},{"accountnumber":30000,"banknumber":30000},{"accountnumber":40000,"banknumber":40000},{"accountnumber":50000,"banknumber":50000}]}
```

Is that what you've requested?

**[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5vjt/)**

Comment: Yeah that was exactly what I meant. Tnx a lot!